# Inter-browser communication within local environment?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

If I have Firefox and Chrome browsers (or any two browsers, these are the main ones I use) open at the same time, is it possible for Firefox to communicate with Chrome or vice versa ?

What I mean is, if I am logged into my Google account on Chrome can Firefox see or know this? Can they communicate with each other even if only one of the browser applications is running? And does the answer to the question change depending on which OS you are using?

Comment: i think 'NO'. because session (when u logged in) store in browsers not in OS or other places..

Comment: @Prashant is right - You need to login individually in each browser - and that's not a suitable question for SO since it's not related to programming